# Results of mysqli_query() returning null for last index

Tags: php, mysqli

I am querying like this, in snippet below 1st loop takes column names and second loops push values in another array(i know this may not be an optimal way but this is what came in my mind and is solving my task). The problem is

```
$results = '';
$dataArray = array();
$columns_array = array();
$dataArray = array();
$results = mysqli_query($mysqli, ("SELECT
  DISTINCT states_drg.`Provider State`,
  SUM(states_drg.`Total Discharges`) AS discharges
 FROM states_drg
 GROUP BY states_drg.`Provider State`")
);
$columns_names = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
foreach ($columns_names as $key => $value) {
    array_push($columns_array, $key);
}
array_push($dataArray, $columns_array);

foreach ($results as $result) {
    array_push($dataArray, mysqli_fetch_row($results));
}
 print_r($dataArray);
echo json_encode($dataArray, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
exit;
);
```

Query runs absolutely fine in query browser, but when I take dump of  print_r($dataArray); I get only 26 records where as I have around 51 records in total if I run the Query in Query Browser.

Comment: What the heck is `$results = mysqli_query($mysqli, ("$results = '';` supposed to do?

Comment: Format properly, it's unreadable

Comment: @RocketHazmat: imy mistake i will correct prob copy paste

Comment: `$results` is a result resource, but you are attempting to `foreach()` over it. That's not going to work

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: very true its just a work around to save time over simple for loop as you can see inside its body what i am doing. then you will understand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using mysqli totally wrong.

```
foreach($results as $result)
```

is **NOT** how you fetch data from a query result. You should have

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $dataArray[] = $row;
}
```

And not to mention the multiple syntax errors in your pasted code...

Comment: yes there are errors in script coz when i submitted the question i got error and when i reposted it , i think i pasted data twice

Comment: Also when you do `$columns_names = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);` you're going to remove the first element from your result. Why are you building an array of column names? Shouldn't you know what columns are in your DB?

Comment: @UptownApps: i stated problem clearly that i am extracting column names ofc i know column names, but its required for some buisness logic

Comment: @marc B: I dont need associative array i needed array of array, so its just a work around, i am getting data , but its like half of total data

Comment: yes, because you're fetching the data incorrectly. `$results` is a mysqli resource handle. it's NOT an array you can loop on.